# Is there a way to disable database encryption before initial encryption completes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I am able to start, suspend, and resume encryption. Once started I can't find a way to disable encryption until initial encryption completes. Is there a way to accomplish that?

For example...

```
-- enable encryption
ALTER DATABASE Test
SET ENCRYPTION ON

-- wait a few minutes and check progress, finding it is only 0.00001% complete :(
SELECT DB_NAME(database_id), encryption_state, percent_complete
FROM sys.dm_database_encryption_keys 

-- performance is terrible so suspend
ALTER DATABASE Test
SET ENCRYPTION SUSPEND

-- consider options and decide to just forget about it, turn off encryption
ALTER DATABASE Test
SET ENCRYPTION OFF

-- lol, nope
Cannot disable database encryption while an encryption, decryption, or key change scan is in progress.
ALTER DATABASE statement failed
```

Answer (score 1):

The doc lists a few [Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption?view=sql-server-ver15#restrictions) regarding the encryption process:

> The following operations are disallowed during the CREATE DATABASE
> ENCRYPTION KEY, ALTER DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY, DROP DATABASE
> ENCRYPTION KEY, and ALTER DATABASE...SET ENCRYPTION statements:
>
> - [...]
> - Using an ALTER DATABASE command

By the doc you shouldn't be allowed even to use the `SET ENCRYPTION SUSPEND` since it is an `ALTER DATABASE` command. Possibly an outdated/misleading text from the doc, but since the command to turn encryption off is the one you used and the error message was clear, I'd say there's no way other than to wait until it finishes the encryption to turn it off (there might be a catch when [Removing TDE](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/removing-tde)).